# Canvas not showing correcty when online

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

**The Problem**

I have created a menu for a game that I am creating (Pacifist Pirate, cool name if I say so myself), I am having problems when trying to view the canvas online. Nothing is showing on the canvas itself, although the logo and buttons do appear for a split second.

**The Question**

Why is it showing perfectly when viewing it offline but not when I put it online? It seems to be stopping at this line in the debugger...

```
timerId = setInterval("update()", 1000/frames);
```

Here is what it looks like offline:

[image: Offline image of canvas] 

The background scrolls upwards.

Here is what it looks like online:

[image: Online image of canvas]

Logo and buttons flash for a split second.

**The Code**

The JavaScript

```
<script type="text/javascript">

            //Referencing the canvas
            var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
            var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
            var width = canvas.getAttribute('width');
            var height = canvas.getAttribute('height');

            //Finding the position of the mouse
            var mouseX;
            var mouseY;

            //Images
            var bgImage = new Image();
            var logoImage = new Image();
            var playImage = new Image();
            var instructImage = new Image();
            var settingsImage = new Image();
            var aboutImage = new Image();
            var peaceImage = new Image();

            var backgroundY = 0;
            var speed = 1;

            //Arrays below used for mouse over function
            var buttonX = [130,110,130,160];
            var buttonY = [100,140,180,220];
            var buttonWidth = [96,260,182,160];
            var buttonHeight = [40,40,40,40];

            var peaceX = [0,0];
            var peaceY = [0,0];
            var peaceWidth = 35;
            var peaceHeight = 35;

            var peaceVisible = false;
            var peaceSize = peaceWidth;
            var peaceRotate = 0;

            var frames = 30;
            var timerId = 0;
            var fadeId = 0;

            peaceImage.src = "Images/peace.png";
            bgImage.onload = function(){
                context.drawImage(bgImage, 0, backgroundY);
            };
            bgImage.src = "Images/Background.png";
            logoImage.onload = function(){
                context.drawImage(logoImage, 50, -10);
            }
            logoImage.src = "Images/logo.png";
            playImage.onload = function(){
                context.drawImage(playImage, buttonX[0], buttonY[0]);
            }
            playImage.src = "Images/play.png";
            instructImage.onload = function(){
                context.drawImage(instructImage, buttonX[1], buttonY[1]);
            }
            instructImage.src = "Images/instructions.png";
            settingsImage.onload = function(){
                context.drawImage(settingsImage, buttonX[2], buttonY[2]);
            }
            settingsImage.src = "Images/settings.png";
            aboutImage.onload = function(){
                context.drawImage(aboutImage, buttonX[3], buttonY[3]);
            }
            aboutImage.src = "Images/about.png";

            timerId = setInterval("update()", 1000/frames);

            canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", checkPos);
            canvas.addEventListener("mouseup", checkClick);

            function update() {
                clear();
                move();
                draw();
            }
            function clear() {
                context.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);
            }
            function move(){
                backgroundY -= speed;
                if(backgroundY == -1 * height){
                    backgroundY = 0;
                }
                if(peaceSize == peaceWidth){
                    peaceRotate = -1;
                }
                if(peaceSize == 0){
                    peaceRotate = 1;
                }
                peaceSize += peaceRotate;
            }


            function draw(){
                context.drawImage(bgImage, 0, backgroundY);
                context.drawImage(logoImage, 50,-10);
                context.drawImage(playImage, buttonX[1], buttonY[0]);
                context.drawImage(instructImage, buttonX[2], buttonY[1]);
                context.drawImage(settingsImage, buttonX[2], buttonY[2]);
                context.drawImage(aboutImage, buttonX[3], buttonY[3]);
                    if(peaceVisible == true){
                    context.drawImage(peaceImage, peaceX[0] - (peaceSize/2), peaceY[0], peaceSize, peaceHeight);
                    context.drawImage(peaceImage, peaceX[2] - (peaceSize/2), peaceY[2], peaceSize, peaceHeight);
                }
            }

            function checkPos(mouseEvent){
                if(mouseEvent.pageX || mouseEvent.pageY == 0){
                    mouseX = mouseEvent.pageX - this.offsetLeft;
                    mouseY = mouseEvent.pageY - this.offsetTop;
                }else if(mouseEvent.offsetX || mouseEvent.offsetY == 0){
                    mouseX = mouseEvent.offsetX;
                    mouseY = mouseEvent.offsetY;
                }
                for(i = 0; i < buttonX.length; i++){
                    if(mouseX > buttonX[i] && mouseX < buttonX[i] + buttonWidth[i]){
                        if(mouseY > buttonY[i] && mouseY < buttonY[i] + buttonHeight[i]){
                            peaceVisible = true;
                            peaceX[0] = buttonX[i] - (peaceWidth/2) - 2;
                            peaceY[0] = buttonY[i] + 2;
                            peaceX[1] = buttonX[i] + buttonWidth[i] + (peaceWidth/2); 
                            peaceY[1] = buttonY[i] + 2;
                        }
                    }else{
                        peaceVisible = false;
                    }
                }
            }
            function checkClick(mouseEvent){
                for(i = 0; i < buttonX.length; i++){
                    if(mouseX > buttonX[i] && mouseX < buttonX[i] + buttonWidth[i]){
                        if(mouseY > buttonY[i] && mouseY < buttonY[i] + buttonHeight[i]){
                            fadeId = setInterval("fadeOut()", 1000/frames);
                            clearInterval(timerId);
                            canvas.removeEventListener("mousemove", checkPos);
                            canvas.removeEventListener("mouseup", checkClick);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            function fadeOut(){
                context.fillStyle = "rgba(0,0,0, 0.2)";
                context.fillRect (0, 0, width, height);
                time += 0.1;
                if(time >= 2){
                    clearInterval(fadeId);
                    time = 0;
                    timerId = setInterval("update()", 1000/frames);
                    canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", checkPos);
                    canvas.addEventListener("mouseup", checkClick);
                }
            }
</script>
```

http://pastebin.com/v1qqLkpA

Comment: Have you tried opening the browser's console and checking for error messages?

Comment: I never have look with debugging code haha, but no I haven't so il get on that right away.

Comment: If you can, also provide the html of the page, or a complete [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/) or the link to wherever you're uploading this.

Comment: Here is the plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/Wcxaosjrq5tPm97DcUc7?p=preview

Comment: It seems to be stopping at this line in the debugger... timerId = setInterval("update()", 1000/frames);

Comment: I'd suggest putting this up on a web host somewhere so we can see a bit better since it has images etc, failing to load them can cause other errors that make it hard to find the real error. A few quick notes: time is not defined, you are doing `time += 0.1` but not setting time as anything, and your setInterval, you do not need to put it as you have. If you've declared a function you can just refer to it by name so instead of  `setInterval("update()")` you should do `setInterval(update)`

Comment: I have added the variable "var time = 0.0;", I will see if that has helped

Comment: You need to add Background.png to that site

Comment: Glad I could help (Im guessing it was the missing file that broke it). For future reference try googling the errors you see in console log (ctrl shift i), the one I was seeing was stating the canvas was in a 'broken' state which is what happens when you try drawing to it and it fails for example by drawing an image that doesn't exist to it. It's a pretty common problem so easily solved with a google. Good luck with the rest!

Answer (score 1):

I didn't define time nor was the background added correctly. After completing these two steps the canvas works correctly. Thank you Liam Macdonald and K. Gkinis.